# How to connect VNC viewer

Tags: connection, vnc

I am trying to view my RPi 3b desktop through VNC viewer. I have my RPi connected via ethernet to my macbook and have already downloaded updates and upgrades from RPi. I got the IP address using 'hostname -i'. I've pasted that into the VNC viewer app on my mac but after minute or so it returns the same message: 'timed out waiting for response from computer'. I have enabled VNC in the advanced options too and I have rebooted the RPi.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get the RPi to connect?

EDIT

I have RPi 3B. It came with an SD card from RPi with NOOBS already loaded. Through ethernet with my Macbook 2011 terminal I have only run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I have enabled VNC through raspi config. Then I ran

```
curl -L -o VNC.tar.gz realvnc.com/download/binary/latest/debian/arm 

tar xvf VNC.tar.gz 

sudo dpkg -i VNC-Server-5.3.2-Linux-ARM.deb 

sudo vnclicense -add <my-license-key> 

sudo vncpasswd /root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11
```

Comment: Your question is lacking detail - including EXACTLY what commands you have used. If you are trying to use RealVNC you will need to install their viewer on the Mac. If you want to use vnc:// on the Mac you need to use `tightvncserver` on the Pi.

Comment: Sorry, ok so for background I have RPi 3B. It came with an SD card from RPi with NOOBS already loaded. Through ethernet with my Macbook 2011 terminal I have only run sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade. I have enabled VNC through raspi config. Then I ran 

$ curl -L -o VNC.tar.gz https://www.realvnc.com/download/binary/latest/debian/arm/

$ tar xvf VNC.tar.gz

$ sudo dpkg -i VNC-Server-5.3.2-Linux-ARM.deb

$ sudo vnclicense -add <my-license-key>

$ sudo vncpasswd /root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11

Comment: Do not put detail in Comments - edit it into your post. Also include what you are doing on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have been following some other instructions, NOT those on the [PIXEL](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/) post.

You should have done `sudo apt-get install realvnc-vnc-server` to install in a existing Raspbian (it should already be there in a new install).

Who knows what you have now? Undo what you have done and follow the official instructions.

Answer (score 0):

VNC server should already be installed and should appear next to the clock after enabling it in raspi-config. If possible, you should also consider connecting the RPi to your router (by Wi-Fi or Ethernet), not straight to your Macbook, as this could require more configuration on your Macbook for your Raspberry to get an IP address and access to the internet.